# error registering mscomm32.ocx

Tags: windows, vb.net, sms

Can somebody tell me how to register mscomm32.ocx. I pasted it in system32 and then tried to register using "regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\mscomm32.ocx" . Even then i got some error message something like this:
"the file was loaded but it is unable to register error 0x8002801". I use 32 bit OS Windows 7
I would be pleased if someone helped me with this.

Comment: You indicate you are using vb.net.  I hope you realize that com functions are built into the framework and you shouldn't need mscomm32.ocx.  See: System.IO.Ports.SerialPort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to run in it as an administrator.  My recommendation would be to start a command prompt as the administrator (right-click on the Command Prompt icon in the Start menu and select "Run as Administrator").

That's a guess based on this article - [DLLRegisterserver failed with error code 0x8002801](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/dllregisterserver-failed-with-error-code-0x8002801/403ee0d0-895b-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5)